# Getting blocked while using Scrapy (With User Agent)

Tags: web-scraping, https, scrapy, header, user-agent

I am trying to scrape a casual sports-team website in my country that keeps blocking my Scrapy attempts. I have tried setting a User Agent, but without any success.. as soon as i run Scrapy, I get the 429 Unknown Status. Not one 200 success. I am able to visit the website in my browser so I know my IP is not blocked. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is the code I am using:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class QuoteSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Quote"
    allowed_domains = ["avaldsnes.spoortz.no"]
    start_urls = ["https://avaldsnes.spoortz.no/portal/arego/club/7"]

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow="")),)
    custom_settings = {"USER_AGENT": "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"}

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.request.headers)
```

I tried Crawling the website for it´s links, But not one attempt succeeded. Right now the user agent is set as Google Bot, but I have tried regular ones as well.

Comment: Most likely the site uses TLS fingerprinting and detects that you use Python. Python is common language for web scraping tools and thus often blocked by site protectors like cloudfront.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to set the headers (and not just the user agent).

```py
from scrapy.spiders import Rule, CrawlSpider
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class QuoteSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "Quote"
    allowed_domains = ["avaldsnes.spoortz.no"]
    start_urls = ["https://avaldsnes.spoortz.no/portal/arego/club/7"]

    headers = {
        "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "DNT": "1",
        "Host": "avaldsnes.spoortz.no",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest": "document",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode": "navigate",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site": "none",
        "Sec-Fetch-User": "?1",
        "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36"
    }

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow="")),)

    custom_settings = {
        'DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS': headers
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response.request.headers)
```

**Output:**

```py
[scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://avaldsnes.spoortz.no/portal/arego/club/7> (referer: None)
...
...
...
```